# How to kill a process in Unix that is often sleeping?

Tags: shell, unix, scripting

I have a Unix shell script that is as follows:

```
(
  # Trap the HUP signal so it doesn't kill me
  trap "" HUP
  # Redirect stderr to /dev/null
  exec 2>/dev/null
  # Redirect stdin from /dev/null
  exec 0</dev/null
  # Redirect stdout to logfile
  exec 1>${LOG}

  while [ 1 ]
  do
    ps -ewwo pcpu,pid,ppid,comm,time,etime,thcount,scount,fuser,args | grep -v "migration" | grep -v "watchdog" | grep -v "ksoftirqd"
    sleep 600
  done
) &
```

I want this to run in the background during some tests I am running to capture process information. It runs "ps" with some options and then sleeps for 10 minutes and I want it to run indefinitely (as my tests vary in length).

My problem is that I have no way to stop this - doing a "ps -ef" only shows me the "sleep 600" command and I have no way of breaking the loop. Is there a way to kill this script or would it be better to write it so not to include a never ending loop? My only thought is to write the script to end execution after a certain time limit (ie several sets of 10 minutes) but I would prefer not to have to edit the script before each test.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The shell subprocess invoked by the `( ... ) &` construct, and all its children, will be in their own *process group*.

```
$ ps -e -o pid,pgid,ppid,tty,comm
PID  PGID  PPID TT       COMMAND
...
2827  2827  2147 pts/1    bash
2832  2827  2827 pts/1    sleep
...
```

The entire process group can be killed in a single action by specifying a negative number as the process ID to `kill`.  (To do this you must also specify a signal number.)

```
$ kill -15 -2827
[2]+  Terminated              ( trap "" HUP; exec 2> /dev/null; ...
```

The PGID to kill is guaranteed to be equal to the PID of its *process group leader*, which in this case is the shell subprocess.  So you can modify your code along the lines of

```
(
  # Trap the HUP signal so it doesn't kill me
  trap "" 1
  # ...
) &

# the special shell variable $! contains the PID of the most recently
# started background process
SUBPROCESS="$!"

# and later when you want to shut it all down again
kill -15 "-$SUBPROCESS"

# ensuring the subprocess is killed with the script would also be a good idea
trap "kill -15 '-$SUBPROCESS'" 0 1 2 3 15
```

(Note: `kill -NAME` and `trap "..." NAME` are **not** portable shell; however, the meanings of signal numbers 1 through 15 **are** portable all the way back to V7. If total portability is not an overriding concern, *don't write a shell script*; the moment you are tempted to reach for an unportable feature, instead stop and rewrite the entire thing in Perl, which is not only a superior programming language, it's **more** likely to be available on a randomly chosen Unix box than Bash is.  Your future self will thank you.)

(Note to pedants: sadly, no readily available version of POSIX.1 can be taken as the reference for what is and is not portable shell, because several major proprietary-Unix vendors froze their shell environments in 1995 plus or minus two years.  For *complete* portability, as e.g. required for `autoconf` scripting, I'm not aware of a reliable test other than "does this work with Solaris `/bin/sh`?"  (Just be glad you no longer have to dig up access to HP-UX, IRIX, and AIX as well.)  However, I am under the impression that you *can* code to POSIX.1-2001, although *not* -2008, if you're only interested in portability to the open-source BSDs, full-scale desktop or server Linux, and OSX. I am also under the impression that Android, busybox, and various other embedded environments do *not* provide all of -2001.)

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't true for nested subshells - they all remain in the same PGID of first subshell as shows output of command ( echo $$ $BASH_SUBSHELL $BASHPID; ( echo $$ $BASH_SUBSHELL $BASHPID ; export AAA=$$; export BBB=$BASHPID; ps -e -o pid,pgid,ppid,tty,comm | grep -E "$AAA|$BBB" )&  sleep 1 )&

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this. One relatively easy one would be like this:

```
FILENAME=/tmp/some_unusual_name_that_would_normally_never_exist

touch ${FILENAME}

while [[ -r ${FILENAME} ]]
do
  ps ....
  sleep ....
done
```

Then when you want to kill your loop, just remove the file. It'll abort the loop the next time it checks...

Answer (score 1):

We're getting into bash golf here, but if don't want to wait the 600 seconds for it to exit, you can have it listen on a named pipe (a.k.a. "fifo") and exit once you talk into the pipe:

```
# this will be our fifo
pipe=/tmp/testpipe

# remove it when we exit
trap "rm -f $pipe" EXIT

# take care of our children if we're killed 
trap "kill -15 '-$$'" 0 1 2 3 15

# create the pipe
if [[ ! -p $pipe ]]; then
    mkfifo $pipe
fi

# put it in a function so we can background it
function ps_and_sleep() {
    while [ 1 ]
    do
        ps -ewwo pcpu,pid,ppid,comm,time,etime,thcount,scount,fuser,args | grep -v "migration" | grep -v "watchdog" | grep -v "ksoftirqd"
        sleep 600
    done
}

#... and background it
ps_and_sleep &

# the moment somebody does this:
#     echo stopitnow > /tmp/testpipe
# then we'll get the message, kill the child, and exit
if read line <$pipe; then
    kill -15 -$$
    exit
fi
```

Props to http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/using-named-pipes-fifos-bash