# Linux: How to kill Sleep

Tags: linux, bash, sleep

More of a conceptual question. If I write a bash script that does something like

```
control_c()
{
echo goodbye
exit #$
}

trap control_c SIGINT

while true
do
sleep 10 #user wants to kill process here.
done
```

control+c won't exit when sleep 10 is running. Is it because linux sleep ignores SIGINT? Is there a way to circumvent this and have the user be able to cntrl+c out of a sleep?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26530146/how-to-kill-a-process-in-unix-that-is-often-sleeping

Answer (score 13):

What you are describing is consistent with the interrupt signal going to only your `bash` script, not the process group. Your script gets the signal, but `sleep` does not, so your trap cannot execute until after `sleep` completes. The standard trick is to run `sleep` in the background and `wait` on it, so that `wait` receives the interrupt signal. You should also then explicitly send `SIGINT` to any child processes still running, to ensure they exit.

```
control_c()
{
echo goodbye
kill -SIGINT $(jobs -p)
exit #$
}

trap control_c SIGINT

while true
do
sleep 10 &
wait
done
```

Comment: `ctrl-d` or `ctrl-c` (prints `^C`) had no affect is it normal?

Answer (score 1):

> control+c won't exit when sleep 10 is running.

That's not true. control+c DOES exit, even if sleep is running.

Are you sure your script is executing in bash? You should explicitly add "#!/bin/bash" on the first line.

Comment: When I run  the script on my system (after adding `#!/bin/bash`), typing Ctrl-C before the `sleep 10` finishes causes the script to terminate after printing `goodbye`.

Answer (score 0):

Since sleep is not bash function but external app, I guess Ctrl+C gets caught by sleep process, which normally should terminate it.
So for contorl_c function to be executed while in sleep, user must press Ctrl+C twice: 1st - to exit sleep, 2nd to get caught by bash trap.