# How to immediately skip loop and go to trap on kill command to process? [BASH]

Tags: bash

My script:

```
#!/bin/bash
finish() {
    echo "[$(date -u)] I was terminated."
    exit
}
trap finish SIGINT SIGTERM
echo "pid is $$"
while true
do
    echo 'I am running'
    sleep 15    
done
```

When I send command `kill -SIGTERM <pid>` to the process running my script I have to wait till `sleep 15` would be executed. I googled but didn't find any answers how to immediately break out of the loop and go to executing `trap` when I send `kill` command.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This question has been more or less answered here: [Linux: How to kill Sleep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32041674/linux-how-to-kill-sleep). In short, the `bash` shell executing the script gets the kill signal, but the `sleep` call does not.

If you want a process to sleep you can execute the `sleep` in the background while you do a `wait` on it. That way, the parent process will get your signal and be free to deal with it. In your code:

```
#!/bin/bash
finish() {
    echo "[$(date -u)] I was terminated."
    exit
}
trap finish SIGINT SIGTERM
echo "pid is $$"
while true
do
    echo 'I am running'
    sleep 15 &
    wait
done
```

Bear in mind that your kill signal will be caught by the parent process which will terminate immediately, but the `sleep 15` will still run in the background until it finishes. You may kill this sleeping process by adding `kill $!` which kills the last background process executed by `bash`.

One final remark. `wait` may wait for one or more processes to finish. With no arguments it will wait for all the child processes to finish. It will also return the status of the last process that finished if a process was specified. If not (like in the example), it will return 0.

Comment: put `kill $!` before exit, then it will terminate sleep command as well.

Comment: @Ipor Sircer, this is true. I have added an explanation. Thanks.